# Odd colouring in solarized vim

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have installed Solarized for Vim, as well as for my terminal app, but experience strange background colours. I see the same problems with both iTerm2 on mac running Vim 7.2 on Debian 6, and Putty on win7 running Vim 7.3 on Redhat EL5.9.

Symptoms: The code get the same background as the line numbers. Only strings and reserved words seem to get the correct (lighter) background colour.

Here is an image showing the problem:

[image]

And this is how it should look (screenshot from Solarized home page):

[image]

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: The Solarized issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues).

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Since this happened in more than one setup and I couldn't find anyone else having the problem, I figured it may be a configuration problem. But I'll consider filing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using *PuTTY*, I had to set the `Terminal-type string` (under Connection, Data) to `xterm-256color` instead of `xterm`.

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 130](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/130) answers this (perhaps it is you?)

> If I use PuTTy with the default settings ( not changing to putty-256color ) then the colors are not correctly allocated.
>
> I noticed this line
>
> ```
> elseif g:solarized_termcolors != 256 && &t_Co >= 16
> ```
>
> checks to see if `t_Co > = 16` but Putty identifies itself or at least the variable is `8` which causes the else statement to run.
>
> If I change that statement to:
>
> ```
> elseif g:solarized_termcolors != 256 && &t_Co >= 8
> ```
>
> then everything works as it should. I don't know how this would affect other terminals but I thought you should know that this is indeed broken and changing that value or adding another conditional would fix this problem.
>
> As a fix in the meantime if anyone has this problem they can simply set t_Co to equal 16 in their vimrc and that appears to fix the problem.